# Manga where the protagonist goes to an island searching for someone and builds a fortress to protect themselves

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character went to an island to find someone. It may have been his father or his friend (I forgot) but, little did he know that the island is weird and people from the other side won't let them ride the boat.

I guess they built a fortress so that the monster?/people who became weird can't come. I remember the remaining chapter I read was he was trying to escape from the island and go back where he came from.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What do you mean by "the other side?"  The other side of the island?